# Remove duplicate elements and take one element from two array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays below,

```js
let array_one = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; //first array
let array_two = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; //second array

//I need [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In array_one and array_two has one common element that is `5` but I need this `5` only one time. I don't need to remove the duplicate elements but need one single element.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve the solution?

Comment: That the data comes from two arrays isn't really relevant; methodology is the same.

Comment: See also [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1584370/215552)

Comment: Thanks. I searched for it but I don't know why I didn't find it.

Comment: Check this : 

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }

    let arr = [...array_one,...array_two];

arr.filter(onlyUnique);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, It should work for you

```
    function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }

    let arr = [...array_one,...array_two];

arr.filter(onlyUnique);
```